# Differentiable but not continuously differentiable.

Tags: derivatives

Given $f: \mathbb{R} \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined as
$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}x^2\sin\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)&,x\neq 0\\ 0&,x=0\end{array}\right\}.$$
I am trying to prove $f$ is differentiable at $x=0$ but not continuously differentiable there.

Comment: Outline: use the definition of derivative to compute $f'(0)$, then compute $f'(x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and show $f'(x) \not\to 0$ as $x \to 0$.

Comment: In other words using the definition $ f ' (0) = \lim_{x \to 0} \frac{f(x)-f(0) }{x-0}$ , we have to show that $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2 \sin\left( \frac 1 x \right) - 0 }{x-0}$ exists,  and it does - it equals to zero.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Here is the idea, I'll leave the detailed calculations up to you.

First, use normal differentiation rules to show that if $x\ne0$ then
$$f'(x)=2x\sin\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)-\cos\Bigl(\frac1x\Bigr)\ .\tag{$*$}$$
Then use the definition of the derivative to find $f'(0)$.  You should get
$$f'(0)=0\ .$$
Then show that $f'(x)$ has no limit as $x\to0$, so $f'$ is not continuous at $0$.  (Hint: the first term in $(*)$ tends to $0$; what happens to the second?)

Comment: Picture [here](https://qr.ae/pKx00G)