# Definition of smooth curve

Tags: complex-analysis

> Definition of smooth curve: A parametric curve $\mathrm Z(t)=x(t)+i
> > y(t)$ on $[a,b]$  is called smooth if
>
> 1. $\mathrm Z'(t)=x'(t)+i y'(t)$ exists and continuous on $[a,b]$.
> 2. $\mathrm Z'(t)$ is non zero on $(a,b)$.

But my problem is that why is the word "continuous" written? As We know that differentiability implies continuity.

Answer (score 5):

Differentiability of $Z(t)$ implies continuity of $Z(t)$, but does not imply *the derivative* $Z'(t)$ is continuous, which is what the definition says.

Comment: How is this? Please provide me a proof of this statement.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391544/differentiable-but-not-continuously-differentiable

Comment: My doubt remains as it is. Provide me a simple counter example.

Comment: Most "simple" (to define) functions are analytic. One single counterexample proves the statement "does not imply". You are free to search for more examples on your own.

Comment: Thank you so much