# I am stuck somewhere in this analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Consider a real valued continuous function f on [0,1] such that f is differentiable on (0,1) and f(0)=f(1)=0. Does there exist some c in (0,1) where f(c)=f'(c)?

It seems like the answer is yes. I am trying to show that the graph of f and its derivative cut each other somewhere in (0,1). I tried using Rolle's theorem and the continuity of the derivative, but its not helping. Any constructive suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: How do you know the derivative is continuous?

Comment: Is it possible for a derivative to exist everywhere on an open interval but be discontinuous?

Comment: @angryavian Oops... I meant the intermediate value property of the derivative. It comes under the heading "the continuity of the derivatives" in Rudin.

Comment: @RobertShore See [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391544/differentiable-but-not-continuously-differentiable) for an example

Comment: @robert shore yes, please look at example 5.6(b) of Rudin (Third Edition) on page 106.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Define $g:[0,1]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $x \mapsto e^{-x}f(x)$ This is continuous on $[0,1]$ and differentiable on $(0,1)$. Also the values at the end points are equal. So use Rolle's theorem to conclude that $g'(c)=0$ for some $c\in (0,1)$ which gives you $f(c)=f'(c)$

Comment: Nice....thanks...onek sundor!