# differentiability of f:$\mathbb {R} \rightarrow \mathbb {R}$ at $x=x_0$ imply continuous of f' at $x=x_0$

Tags: analysis, real-numbers

For the fucntion $f:\mathbb{R}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ which are differentiable at $x=x_0$
imply $f'$ is continuous at $x=x_0$?

$f$ is differentiable at $x=x_0$ when $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta>0, c\in \mathbb{R} \ s.t$
$$0<|x-x_0|<\delta \ \ imply \ \ |\frac{f(x)-f(x_0)}{x-x_0}-c|<\epsilon $$

in this case we let $c=f'(x_0)$

if $f'(x)$ is defined $\forall x \in\mathbb{R}$ from the above definition of derivative.
can we prove $\forall \epsilon >0,\exists \delta>0,\ s.t$
$$|x-x_0|<\delta \ \ imply \ \ |f'(x)-f'(x_0)|<\epsilon $$?

I don't have any proof of above problem or counterexample, please help me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Differentiability does not necessarily imply the derivative is continuous. For a counterexample, see [Differentiable but not continuously differentiable.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391544/differentiable-but-not-continuously-differentiable).

The class of differentiable functions that do have a continuous derivative are denoted $C^1$.

Answer (score 2):

$f(x)=x^{2}\sin (\frac1 x)$ for $x \neq 0$, $ f(0)=0$ defines a function which is differentiable at $0$ but its deriavtive is not continuous at $0$. In fact, $f'(x)$ does not even have a limit as $x \to 0$.

Comment: Thanks I understand that