# A function is continuously differentiable in an open neighborhood of $x_o$ and differentiable at $x_o$, is it continuously differentiable at $x_o$?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

Until I thought about this, I would have confidently answered *yes* to my question.

Let $f:\mathbb{R\to\mathbb{R}}$ be differentiable at $x_{0},$ and continuously differentiable on some **open** neighborhood $\mathcal{N}$ of $x_{o}$. It follows that $f$ is continuous at $x_{o}.$ But, since $\mathcal{N}$ is open, $x_{o}$ is not necessarily in $\mathcal{N}$. So is it possible that

$$\lim_{\delta \to 0} f^{\prime}\left(x_{o}+\delta\right)\ne f^{\prime}\left(x_{o}\right)?$$

For $\Delta x\ne0$ and $x_{o}+\delta+\Delta x\in\mathcal{N},$ the continuity of $f$ gives us,

$$\underset{\delta\to\mathfrak{0}}{\text{Lim}}\frac{\mathit{f}\left(x_{o}+\delta+\Delta x\right)-f\left(x_{o}+\delta\right)}{\Delta x}=\frac{\mathit{f}\left(x_{o}+\Delta x\right)-f\left(x_{o}\right)}{\Delta x},$$

and therefore

$$\underset{\Delta x\to\mathfrak{0}}{\text{Lim}}\left[\underset{\delta\to\mathfrak{0}}{\text{Lim}}\frac{\mathit{f}\left(x_{o}+\delta+\Delta x\right)-f\left(x_{o}+\delta\right)}{\Delta x}\right]=f^{\prime}\left(x_{o}\right).$$

We also have

$$\underset{\Delta x\to\mathfrak{0}}{\text{Lim}}\frac{f\left(x_{o}+\delta+\Delta x\right)-f\left(x_{o}+\delta\right)}{\Delta x}=f^{\prime}\left(x_{o}+\delta\right).$$

But can we conclude $\underset{\delta \to\mathfrak{0}}{\text{Lim}}\mathit{f}^{\prime}\left(x_{o}+\delta\right)=\mathit{f}^{\prime}\left(x_{o}\right)?$  That is, for all $\epsilon>0$ can we find $\delta$ and $\Delta x$ such that $x_{o}+\delta+\Delta x\in\mathcal{N}$ and

$$\epsilon>\left|\frac{f\left(x_{o}+\delta+\Delta x\right)-f\left(x_{o}+\delta\right)}{\Delta x}-\mathit{f}^{\prime}\left(x_{o}\right)\right|?$$

Another way of stating the question is; can we reverse the order of the limit operation so that

$$\underset{\Delta x\to\mathfrak{0}}{\text{Lim}}\left[\underset{\delta\to\mathfrak{0}}{\text{Lim}}\frac{\Delta\mathit{f}_{x_{o}}\left(\delta+\Delta x\right)}{\Delta x}\right]=\underset{\delta\to\mathfrak{0}}{\text{Lim}}\left[\underset{\Delta x\to\mathfrak{0}}{\text{Lim}}\frac{\Delta\mathit{f}_{x_{o}}\left(\delta+\Delta x\right)}{\Delta x}\right]?$$

Comment: I don't understand the question at all. An open neighboghood of $x_0$ surely contains $x_0$. You probably mean  a **deleted neighborhood** of $x_0$.

Comment: Based on the title, isn't the "usual" example $f(x)=x^2\sin(1/x)$ exactly giving that? https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391544/differentiable-but-not-continuously-differentiable (I am assuming by neighborhood you mean deleted neighborhood, otherwise the question is vacuous) [Edit: "deleted neighborhood", "pointed neighborhood" was a bad French translation)

Comment: @ClementC. That's really the issue.  What is meant by "neighborhood".  See https://www.scribd.com/read/282634061/Advanced-Calculus-of-Several-Variables Theorem III 3.3.  I will post a question about that, presently.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy I do not take "open neighborhood $\mathcal{N}$ of x" to mean $x\in\mathcal{N}$.  For the very reason at issue in my question.  I took real analysis 26 years ago, and haven't set foot in a classroom in 25 years.  So, even though I didn't recall the details, I sensed there was an issue; hence the question.

Comment: No problem. The standard terminology is deleted neighorhood but it is not difficult to guess what your question really says.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your $\mathcal N$ is  deleted neighborhhod of $x_0$ then there is a well known counter-example: $f(x)=x^{2} \sin (\frac 1  x)$ for $x \neq 0$ and $f(0)=0$.  In this case $\lim_{x \to 0} f'(x)$ does not even exist.