# Does Edwards need to explicitly state $a\in\mathcal{W}$ in his Inverse Mapping Theorem?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, solution-verification

In view of the answer to my question: [A function is continuously differentiable in an open neighborhood of $x_o$ and differentiable at $x_o$, is it continuously differentiable at $x_o$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/4048215/342834) it seems to me that in the theorem quoted below, Edwards should explicitly state $a\in\mathcal{W}$.  So I ask: is the situation any different in multivariable calculus?  That is, without explicitly stating that $a\in\mathcal{W},$ is Edwards's theorem correct? Is it not possible to have a nonsingular $f^{\prime}\left(a\right),$ and still have $f$ not $\mathscr{C}^1$ at $a$.

C.H. Edwards's [Advanced Calculus of Several Variables](https://store.doverpublications.com/0486683362.html)

> **Theorem III 3.3** Suppose that the mapping $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}^{n}$
> is $\mathscr{C}^{1}$ in a neighborhood $\mathcal{W}$ of the point
> $a$, with the matrix $f^{\prime}\left(a\right)$ being nonsingular.
> Then $f$ is locally invertible--- there exist neighborhoods of $a$
> $\mathcal{U}\subset\mathcal{W}$ and $\mathcal{V}$ of $b=f\left(a\right)$,
> and a one-to-one mapping $g:\mathcal{V}\to\mathcal{W}$ such that

> $$
> g\left(f\left(x\right)\right)=x\text{ for }x\in\mathcal{U},
> $$

> and

> $$
> f\left(g\left(y\right)\right)=y\text{ for }y\in\mathcal{V}.
> $$

> In particular, the local inverse of $g$ is the limit of the sequence
> $\left\{ g_{k}\right\} _{0}^{\infty}$ of successive approximations
> defined inductively by

> $$
> g_{0}\left(y\right)=a,g_{k+1}\left(y\right)=g_{k}\left(y\right)-f^{\prime}\left(a\right)^{-1}\left[f\left(g_{k}\left(y\right)\right)-y\right]
> $$

> for $y\in\mathcal{V}.$

Comment: A neighbourhood of $a$ automatically contains the point $a$ (recall the definition: $N$ is a neighbourhood of $p$ means there exists open $U$ such that $p\in U\subseteq N$).  The world has become a better place when "punctured neighbourhoods" really need the "punctured" adjective every time.

Comment: Edwards doesn't define "neighborhood".  If he had said "open ball", there would have been no problem, since he defines what that means.  I do see that in the Mathematical Appendix to Gravitation and Inertia, Wheeler and Ciufolini define a neighborhood as containing the defining point.

Answer (score 1):

In the definitive section I-7, Edwards states:

> Let $\mathcal{D}$ be a subset of $\mathbb{R}^{n},$ and $f$ a *mapping* of $\mathcal{D}$ into $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ (that is, a rule that associates with each point $x\in\mathcal{D}$ a point $f\left(x\right)\in\mathbb{R}^{n}$). We write $f:\mathcal{D}\to\mathbb{R}^{n},$ and call $\mathcal{D}$ the *domain* (of definition) of $f.$

> In order to define $\lim_{\mathbf{x}\to\mathbf{a}}f\left(\mathbf{x}\right),$ the *limit* of $f$ at $\mathbf{a},$ it will be necessary that $f$ be defined at points arbitrary close to $\mathbf{a},$ that is, that $\mathcal{D}$ contains points arbitrarily close to $\mathbf{a}.$ However **we do not want to insist that $\mathbf{a}\in\mathcal{D},$ that is, that $f$ be defined at $\mathbf{a}.$** For example, when we define the derivative $f^{\prime}\left(a\right)$ of a real-valued single-variable function as the limit of its difference quotient at $a.$

> $f^{\prime}\left(a\right)=\lim_{x\to a}\frac{f\left(x\right)-f\left(a\right)}{x-a},$

> this difference quotient is not defined at $a.$

To my knowledge, Edwards gives no formal definition of *neighborhood.*  There are a number of similar examples where we assume something to be true for points arbitrarily close to a point $\mathbf{a}$, but not at the point $\mathbf{a}.$ So I left open the possibility that *open neighborhood $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathbf{a}$* allows $\mathbf{a}\notin\mathcal{U}.$

In the **Mathematical Appendix** to [Gravitation and Inertia,](https://press.princeton.edu/books/hardcover/9780691033235/gravitation-and-inertia) by Ignazio Ciufolini and John Archibald Wheeler is found:

> A *neighborhood* of a point $P$ is a set of $\mathcal{S}$ containing an open set containing $P.$

At first, I thought this addresses my question.  But, while composing this answer, it occurred to me that the adjective *open* does not appear in the term defined as *neighborhood.*

So my answer is that Edwards should define what he means by *open neighborhood $\mathcal{U}$ of $\mathbf{a},$* and if, by that definition, *open neighborhood,* does not require $\mathbf{a}\in\mathcal{U},$ the Theorem, as stated, is incorrect.  Otherwise, it is acceptable.