# differentiable function, what statement is false

Tags: calculus

Below is an AP calculus question. Then answer key says the answer is E. But I don't understand if the function is differentiable and f '(3) = 5, then how could the limit not also be 5? I think that if choice E was false then the function is not differentiable.

Does any know of a differentiable function where f '(3) = 5, but the limit of f '(x) at 3 is not also 5?

Or is there something wrong with this question?

[image]

Comment: For a function to be differentiable at a point it needs to be continuous at that point.  There is however no requirement that the function needs to be *twice* differentiable at a point, and no requirement that the derivative be continuous at a point.

Comment: Consider modifying the example found [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1391544/differentiable-but-not-continuously-differentiable) by appropriate translations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$f(x)=\left\{\begin{array}{cc}(x-3)^2 \sin\left( \frac1{x-3}\right ) + 5x-7&&,&x \neq 3\\8&&,&x=3\end{array}\right\}$$

[image]